# Django if value is in list

Tags: python, django, list

I have the code below that returns `8`:

```
resume_menu_a_detail_val = settings.MENU_DETAIL_VALUE_A_DETAILS #8
```

The code below returns this list: `[u'0', u'1', u'22', u'2', u'3', u'4', u'5', u'26', u'6', u'7', u'23', u'8', u'9', u'25', u'11', u'12', u'10', u'13', u'14', u'27', u'15', u'24', u'16', u'17', u'18', u'19', u'20', u'21']`

```
resume_menu_list01 = request.user.get_profile().selected_resume_menu_entries.split(',')
```

The `if` statement below will always return the false condition (the value of `8` is in the list):

```
if resume_menu_a_detail_val in resume_menu_list01:
    return {'resume_menu_list01': 'TRUE'}            
else:
    return {'resume_menu_list01': 'FALSE'}
```

How do I get the if statement to recognise the `8` in the list?

Also, how do I sort the list from lowest to highest value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are comparing strings and integers; they are not the same *type* so they are not equal:

```
>>> u'8' == 8
False
```

They may print the same, but they are not the same thing. You'd have to convert your integer to a `unicode()` string:

```
if unicode(resume_menu_a_detail_val) in resume_menu_list01:
```

To sort `resume_menu_list01`, just call `.sort()` on it:

```
resume_menu_list01.sort()
```

This will sort it lexicographically; in order of their  *characters*; `'21'` sorts before `'3'`, for example. To sort *numerically* you need to tell `sort()` to turn each value to an integer for comparisons:

```
resume_menu_list01.sort(key=int)
```

See the [Python sorting how-to](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/sorting.html) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to look integer `8` into the string that contains character `'8'`. Hence its saying not found.

You may want to change the if to search character `'8'` as

```
    #--v use str()
    if str(resume_menu_a_detail_val) in resume_menu_list01:

        return {'resume_menu_list01': 'TRUE'}

    else:

        return {'resume_menu_list01': 'FALSE'}
```